# Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

Cannot for the life of me get rid of this error - been trying for a day to no avail. `gem pristine --all` did nothing, and neither did deleting and reinstalling bundle. Anyone else come across this and know what to do? I would be externally grateful for the answer!

The full error is here:

> Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gem specs(and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.

and this happens every time I run Rails, or Rails console.

Answer (score 10):

I actually had to delete the `gems` directory in my rvm bundle cache directory. For me that was:

`rm -rf ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@<my-gemset-name-here>/bundler/gems`.

After that I redid the following:

`gem pristine --all`
`bundle install`
`bundle exec spring binstub --all`

and now it works fine.

Comment: You can also get the path straight from RVM: `rm -rf \`rvm gemdir\`/bundler/gems`

Comment: Also, if you have any gems installed in your global gemset you may need to remove them too: `rvm gemset use global; gem pristine --all`, then switch back to your project gemset. Don't forget to run `spring stop` before trying to run any more spring commands.

Answer (score 9):

If you use **rbenv** or nothing instead of RVM, you can uninstall all your gems with

```
$ for i in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall -aIx $i; done
```

If you have a `.bundle` directory you can delete and reinstall your bundle with

```
$ rm -rf .bundle && bundle
```