# Can't start Ruby on Rails server using Ruby 2.6.5 version

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I get this error when I run **rails s**

I had try update all my gems, but didn't works for me :(
When I was using with ruby 2.6.1 everything worked fine.
But I had to update the ruby version because my environment in the Elastic Beanstalk on AWS is works with ruby 2.6.5.

Can anyone help me?

Updating the post...

I tried rebuild all my gems by following the @tadman suggestion. But I still have the same error.

After that I redid the following:

> gem pristine --all
>
> bundle install
>
> bundle exec spring binstub --all

The error I got:

> nimet@nimet-PC:~/Projects/belle.api$ rails s
>   => Booting Puma
>   => Rails 5.2.4 application starting in development 
>   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/puma_http11.so:
>   [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000 ruby 2.6.5p114
>   (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
>
> -- Control frame information ----------------------------------------------- c:0052 p:-11744685087948 s:0281 e:000280 TOP    [FINISH] c:0051 p:---- s:0278
>   e:000277 CFUNC  :require c:0050 p:0008 s:0273 e:000272 BLOCK 
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291 c:0049 p:0068 s:0270 e:000269 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257 c:0048 p:0011 s:0263 e:000262 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291 c:0047 p:0090 s:0257 e:000256 TOP
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:17
>   [FINISH] c:0046 p:---- s:0254 e:000253 CFUNC  :require c:0045 p:0008
>   s:0249 e:000248 BLOCK 
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291 c:0044 p:0068 s:0246 e:000245 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257 c:0043 p:0011 s:0239 e:000238 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291 c:0042 p:0006 s:0233 e:000232 TOP
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:3
>   [FINISH] c:0041 p:---- s:0230 e:000229 CFUNC  :require c:0040 p:0008
>   s:0225 e:000224 BLOCK 
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291 c:0039 p:0068 s:0222 e:000221 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257 c:0038 p:0011 s:0215 e:000214 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291 c:0037 p:0006 s:0209 e:000208 TOP
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:3
>   [FINISH] c:0036 p:---- s:0206 e:000205 CFUNC  :require c:0035 p:0008
>   s:0201 e:000200 BLOCK 
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291 c:0034 p:0068 s:0198 e:000197 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257 c:0033 p:0011 s:0191 e:000190 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291 c:0032 p:0020 s:0185 e:000184 TOP
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/launcher.rb:6
>   [FINISH] c:0031 p:---- s:0182 e:000181 CFUNC  :require c:0030 p:0008
>   s:0177 e:000176 BLOCK 
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291 c:0029 p:0068 s:0174 e:000173 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257 c:0028 p:0011 s:0167 e:000166 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291 c:0027 p:0031 s:0161 e:000160 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:15
>   c:0026 p:0012 s:0152 e:000151 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:65
>   c:0025 p:0195 s:0143 E:000028 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:297
>   c:0024 p:0045 s:0136 E:001a30 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:53 c:0023 p:0042 s:0132 e:000131 BLOCK 
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147
>   [FINISH] c:0022 p:---- s:0128 e:000127 CFUNC  :tap c:0021 p:0030
>   s:0124 e:000123 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142
>   c:0020 p:0064 s:0120 e:000119 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27
>   c:0019 p:0047 s:0112 e:000111 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127
>   c:0018 p:0259 s:0105 e:000104 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392
>   c:0017 p:0043 s:0092 e:000091 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69
>   c:0016 p:0130 s:0085 e:000084 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46
>   c:0015 p:0059 s:0074 e:000073 TOP
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18
>   [FINISH] c:0014 p:---- s:0069 e:000068 CFUNC  :require c:0013 p:0053
>   s:0064 e:000063 TOP    /home/nimet/Projects/belle.api/bin/rails:9
>   [FINISH] c:0012 p:---- s:0060 e:000059 CFUNC  :load c:0011 p:0135
>   s:0055 e:000054 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28
>   c:0010 p:0009 s:0050 e:000049 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7
>   c:0009 p:0014 s:0045 e:000044 METHOD
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30
>   c:0008 p:0295 s:0039 e:000038 TOP
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49
>   [FINISH] c:0007 p:---- s:0033 e:000032 CFUNC  :load c:0006 p:0163
>   s:0028 e:000027 TOP
>   /home/nimet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31
>   [FINISH] c:0005 p:---- s:0022 e:000021 CFUNC  :require c:0004 p:0130
>   s:0017 e:000016 TOP    /home/nimet/Projects/belle.api/bin/spring:15
>   [FINISH] c:0003 p:---- s:0012 e:000011 CFUNC  :load c:0002 p:0018
>   s:0007 E:000098 EVAL   bin/rails:3 [FINISH] c:0001 p:0000 s:0003
>   E:001a40 (none) [FINISH]

Comment: You may need to [rebuild all your gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22387196/warning-running-gem-pristine-all-to-regenerate-your-installed-gemspecs). A hard-crash like this is usually an indication that some compiled gem extensions are broken.

Comment: thanks @tadman, I very noob on Rails...I will try this tip.

Comment: Even rebuilding all my gems (the @tadman suggestion) the problem still the same.

Comment: This could be a bug in Puma, so you may want to check for [issues](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues) or open a new one. It's really hard to say from this ouptut.

Comment: The full output have 2528 lines. I start to think that could be a bug in Puma too. So, I will chek for issues like mine. I'll continue updating this post with de feedbacks I got.

Comment: Until now, I have no ideia about this error. I'll to appreciate all efforts to help me guys.

Comment: You'll need to post an issue unless you can describe how to reproduce this particular problem. The Puma team and Puma users will know better than Stack Overflow's general population.

Comment: Ok @tadman, I'll do that.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error with Rails 6.0.3.3 and Ruby 2.7.1 - however WSL2 in my Terminal works perfectly...

Comment: @LeandroNimet did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, but I had to reinstall all my environment including my operational system. I never knew the real causes of the problem.